# Mobile site shows wrong numbers when tracking privileges

Tags: bug, status-declined, reputation, mobile-web, privileges

This is my activity page on the mobile site:

[image: Stormblessed's activity page on Politics]

A zoom in on the privilege tracker:

[image: Next privilege >1.3k Rep. / Create tag synonyms]

So it says that when I have more than 1,300 reputation, I'll get the privilege. Sounds correct, right? Let's just hop over to the privileges page and show how great it i—***OH NO!!***

[image: 1,250 reputation: create tag synonyms]

**The privilege tracker on mobile shows the wrong amount of reputation necessary to unlock "create tag synonyms" on Beta sites; it should say 1.25K, rather than 1.3K.** Looking at other users' profiles, this problem also happens. This only happens with this privilege, as far as I've noticed.

Comment: The screenshots are through Responsive Design Mode in Firefox because it's easier to use, but the problems are exactly the same on my phone.

Comment: It's likely due to rounding. There's only a single decimal so 1250 is rounded up to 1300.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea if this is correct or not, but there is a definite difference between this privilege and all the other privileges. This is the only privilege which would require an additional character to display, as every other privilege above 1,000 reputation is a multiple of 100 (so the ending zeros can be dropped).

Thus, it may be that only 3 characters can be displayed, and therefore 1.25k has to be rounded up to 1.3k. A similar phenomenon can be observed when viewing people’s reputation; when a new digit gets added to your reputation, another digit gets removed and rounded. For instance, if you have between 10,000 and 99,999 reputation, it will display to the nearest hundred (e.g. 27.4k) but once you hit 100,000 it will only display to the nearest thousand (e.g. 152k).

Comment: But there’s enough space for the accurate number to fit (testing with Inspect Element), so it could be simply fixed.