# There shouldn't be a > in the mobile site's privilege tracker

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, profile-page, mobile-web

On the mobile site, the privilege tracker has a ">" symbol in front of the number of reputation points necessary:

[image: Showing that it has a ">" sign in front of the number of reputation points you need for the next privilege]

This is inaccurate. As soon as this user has exactly 10 reputation, they will have the privilege; people who know a little about math know that this symbol makes it seem like if the user has 10 reputation they won't have the privilege and they'd need to have 11 reputation in order to get it.

**This symbol should be changed; it's misleading and very pointless.**

On what it should be changed to: as pointed out in the comments, a colon wouldn't be so clear. I think that just an "at" would work well. Testing it with wider numbers shows that it still lines up well with them. Here is an anachronistic example of how it would fit with the 1.25K privilege on Beta sites if it were fixed<sup>1</sup>:

[image: "Next privilege at 1.25k Rep." fits fine]

<sup>1</sup><sub>[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331188/399694) is a post I wrote about how it *doesn't* display the right number; I'm using it to show that if it did show the right number, it'd still fit perfectly.</sub>

Comment: What do you propose they use? A - would look like a minus and a | may be conceived as a one. I see no real issue here.

Comment: @DanK A colon would work nicely - `Next Privilege: 10 Rep.`

Comment: @angussidney Would that mean "earn 10 rep to get next privilege" or "next privilege at 10 rep"?

Comment: @ModusTollens it would mean "next privilege at 10 rep" - although, now that you mention it, that specific wording may be even better

Comment: Well, if you are objecting to > on the grounds that it is mathematically inaccurate, the obvious suggestion for a replacement symbol is ≥.

Comment: Completing - there is no more mobile site, so mobile devices will get the same as everyone else.

Comment: @YaakovEllis the [tag:status-completed] tag is wrong/misleading. This make people think there is mobile web and the request was completed today. It is neither of those. When there is a request, removing the basis for the request is not completing it, it is just making the request void. (Just to make it clear, the request is very specific to the mobile web, aka a special view SE had for mobile devices)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I disagree. They had an issue that they reported browsing on mobile devices. This was fixed through the implementation of a feature (fully responsive website eliminating the need for mobile views). Of all the status option, I think that this is the most appropriate.